# wheneven users visit my wordpress website, video popup appears , How should i do that?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want  whenever users open my wordpress website a popup window appears that displays Video(from youtube/ vimeo)   and user have a option to whether  click on play button to watch video on same popup screen or just cross that pop up to visit website, Kindly suggest me some  wordpress plugin or any other solution that solves this issue

Also i used  plugin "Popup with fancybox" but it didn’t work fine , instead of previewing the video it displays the link of that video (attached the image )https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHyq6.jpg

Kindly Help me, Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as though you are using a shortcode for 'popup with fancybox' which includes another shortcode for the embedded video.  So you have a shortcode within a shortcode or something like that.

You might have better luck using a different plugin such as: http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-video-lightbox/installation/.  It seems to do exactly what you want.